# How to use Selenium run IE on Windows 8 with capabilities to IE version 8

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

On my computer is Windows 8 (Internet Explorer 10)

How I can run Internet Explorer with Selenium with browser mode IE8

Here is my Selenium code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","D://workspace//IEDriverServer_x64.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        caps.setCapability(
              InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS
              ,true);
        capab.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
        // i was try this 
        // capab.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "9");
        capab.setCapability("version", "9");

        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
        driver.get(" my url ");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge goes(which is limited), we can run selenium tests only against browsers installed in our systems. I dont think `capab.setCapability("version", "9")` actually starts IE9 because IE9 is not physically present in your machine.

So you'll have to install the older version of the browser.
Another solution is to use GRID to run the tests remotely on another machine which has the required browser.